# Не получается разбить стихотворение по 1 слову в каждой строке в текстовом документе. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, работа-с-текстом

```
inputfile = "word.txt"
outputfile = "word1.txt"
outputfile = "word2.txt"
file = open(inputfile, mode='r', encoding='UTF-8')
file2 = open(outputfile, mode='w', encoding='UTF-8')
file3 = open(outputfile, mode='w', encoding='UTF-8')
for line in file:
         if ' ' in line:        
             file3.write(line.split('\n'))
```

Мне нужно чтобы каждое слово было с большой буквы и начиналось с новой строки. Это я сделал но не могу найти как мне достать все слова из документа и записать их в новый документ но уже чтобы каждое слово было отдельно.
Пример:

```
Буря мглою небо кроет,
Вихри снежные крутя;
То, как зверь, она завоет,
То заплачет, как дитя,
```

Надо:

```
Буря
Мглою
Небо
Кроет
```

и тд..

Comment: нельзя так делать - `outputfile = "word1.txt"
outputfile = "word2.txt"` - вы не создаете две переменных, а просто меняете значение, поэтому file2 и file3 - это один и тот же файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например так:

1. сначала из файла считать все строки в список
2. затем разбить строки из списка в список слов
3. из списка слов сформировать новый список с уже преобразованными словами
4. записать список в файл

код:

```
words = []

# считать данные
fin = open(inputfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8')

lines = fin.readlines()

for line in lines:
    words += line.split()

fin.close()

# сформировать новый массив с первыми буквами
output = list(map(lambda word: word[:1].upper() + word[1:], words))

# записать output в файл
```

или так:

```
output = [word[:1].upper() + word[1:] for word in words]
```

Comment: у строки есть методы capitalize() и title() чтоб не извращаться с word[:1].upper() + word[1:]